# How do I make it so if the user inputs 4, it will show the rules text file?

Tags: java

I'm making a hangman game and I wanted to know how do I make it so if the user inputs 4, it will show the rules text file(rules.txt)

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Hangman
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner guess = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello, and welcome to Hangman!");
    System.out.println("Choose (1)easy   (2)medium   (3)hard (4)rules: ");
    int diff = guess.nextInt(); 
    if(diff==1)
    {
      Play obj = new Play();
        obj.Start(diff);
    }
     if(diff==2)
     {
        Play obj = new Play();
        obj.Start(diff);
      }
      if(diff==3)
      {
        Play obj = new Play();
        obj.Start(3);
      }
      else{
          System.out.print("enter a valid number, please try again");
      }
  }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The `java.nio.file.Files.readString` can read an entire file into memory which you can then print out:

```
if (diff == 4) {
    try {
        System.out.println(Files.readString(Paths.get("rules.txt")));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72621481/19258563) i added what you said and got this

`Hangman.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(Files.readString(Paths.get("rules.txt")));
                                ^
  symbol:   method readString(Path)
  location: class Files
1 error`

Comment: What Java version are you using? Did you organize your imports, i.e., `import java.nio.file.*;`?

Comment: i believe its java 8, and yes i imported

Comment: If you can, please upgrade to Java 11 at least.